# Admin Page Worries

Tags: php, html

I will be very direct with my question. I have been developing web applications for a while, but one thing I haven't been able to overcome is this; Where is the most appropriate location to have an admin page. For instance, How are company like Facebook, Google, Yahoo, BOA, etc doing it? am sick and tired of

http://weblink/admin, or 
http://weblink/administration

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong exactly with having /administration or /admin?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that kind of admin area, lots of sites do it.

Comment: build it into the user section, just have elevated privileges?

Comment: Oh ok then! I was just thinking their is a better way out there. if you guys suggest so, then am fine

Comment: what about /aDm1nIstrAtIon lol

Comment: on my company, it's /onlyus and /tools

Comment: Great! So is it impossible for webcrawlers to scan 'these folders' and find the location in the case of /aDm1nIstrAtIon ? I dont mean to sound ignorant, am just interested in finding all information regarding this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

admin , administration can be easily predicted , and if that script has any vulnerabilities ,it may even be exploited. so use some random string for it.  lol.

if you are using premade scripts like wordpress , every one knows your admin path ( */wp-admin/ )

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I have added learnt something today